# deep-reverse for scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

When entering the list of ((1 2) (3 4)), I want to reverse it, but not so it's ((3 4) (1 2)), which is what reverse does, so I'm trying to write a deep-reverse procedure:

```
(define (deep-reverse l)
  (cond ((null? l) nil)
        (not (pair? (car l)) l)
        (else (append (deep-reverse (cdr l)) (list (car l))))))
```

but it just throws back ((1 2) (3 4)).  What's wrong and how do I get this to work?

Comment: What answer do you want? What is deep-reverse of '(1 (2 3) 4) and '(1 (2 (3 4)))?

Comment: I could see one possibility: reversed lists, within the reversed list `((4 3) (2 1))` in which case you just need to make recursive calls to reverse lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
(define (deep-reverse l) (map reverse l))
```

The above is the simplest possible answer; a real answer depends on exactly what you expect deep-reverse to do.  See my comment to your question.

If you want everything, all the way down:

```
(define (deep-reverse l)
  (if (list? l)
      (reverse (map deep-reverse l))
      l))
```

Here is how it works (correctly):

```
> (deep-reverse '(1 2 ((3.1 3.2) (4) "abc")))
(("abc" (4) (3.2 3.1)) 2 1)
```

Comment: the homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), you shouldn't ask people  to use it anymore

Comment: but this would only work for a single level of lists within the list, right?

Comment: Right.  You want it all the way down?

Answer (score 1):

A good start is the reverse procedure that works for a list. Then modify it to recursively apply to each car of the list:

```
(define (reverse x)
  (define (go items tail)
    (if (null? items) tail
        (go (cdr items) (cons (car items) tail))))
  (go x ()))

(define (deep-reverse x)
  (define (go items tail)
    (cond ((null? items) tail)
          ((not (pair? items)) items)
          (else (go (cdr items) (cons (go (car items) ()) tail)))))
  (go x ()))
```

An application of deep-reverse would be:

```
    (define x (list (list 1 (list 2 3) 4) 5 6 (list 7 8) 9 10)) (display x) (deep-reverse x)

   ((1 (2 3) 4) 5 6 (7 8) 9 10)
=> (10 9 (8 7) 6 5 (4 (3 2) 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also deep reverse the `car` in the code. Otherwise you are not deep reversing the front-most part of the list.

```
(define (deep-reverse l)
  (cond ((null? l) nil)
        (not (pair? (car l)) l)
        (else (append (deep-reverse (cdr l)) (list (deep-reverse (car l)))))))
```